# Can't find device when trying to install Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu and when I am presented with the Partitioning menu I have no devices that I can select. however from the "try Ubuntu" area I can see my hard drive mounted.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you have any data you want to keep on your hard drive?

Comment: Do you know in which system your HDD is formatted (FAT32, NTFS, etc.)?

Comment: It is formatted in NTFS, and no I do not have any data I want to keep on it

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Did your system come pre-installed with Windows 8 by chance? (UEFI BIOS)?